# New columns based on calculations of on existing columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Original data frame in R
df_orginal

```
AB    CD  EF  GH
A     0   12  M
A     0   13  F
A     0   14  F
A     1   16  M
A     1   17  F
A     1   18  M
A     1   18  M
A-2   0   78  M
A-2   0   12  M
A-2   0   12  F
A-2   1   12  F
A-2   1   47  M
A-2   1   34  F
```

Outputs I would like:
df_1 = max, min, mean of EF based on AB
The code I am attempting to use is:

```
df_1 <- df_original %>% group_by(AB, CD) 
df_1 <- summarise(EF, max, min, mean)
```

Error: Problem with summarize() input...1
x Input ...1 must be a vector, not a function
Input ...1 is max

```
AB  CD  Max  Min  Mean 
A   0   14   12   13
A   1   18   16   17.25
A-2 0   78   12   34
A-2 1   47   12   31
```

And
df_2 = total number of M or F from GH based on AB and CD

```
df_2 <- df_original %>% group_by(AB, CD, GH) 
df_2 <-  summarise(GH, sum)
```

And I am having trouble writing the rest of this code

```
AB  CD  M_total  F_total
A   0   1        2
A   1   3        1
A-2 0   2        1
A-2 1   1        2
```

Comment: Pivoting is not what you need: that technique preserves all data, it does not summarize. In the link I'm marking this a dupe of, there are several answers that suggest (for example) `dplyr`'s `summarize` function; simply calculate multiple columns (instead of "just mean" as they tend to show there).

Comment: (While you do mention trying `summarize`, what you ask for is perfectly addressed in that link. If you still do not get it to work, then (1) [edit] the question, and show your code and errors, it does nothing for us for you to say *"only getting error messages"*, we need to see the **code** and the literal **errors**; (2) ping me to reopen the question. Good luck!)